# Why would "Disallow: /*?s=" be used in a robots.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt

We got notice from Google's Search Console that one of our blog posts couldn't be crawled.  When inspecting the URL from the Google Search Console it reports that the paged was blocked by the following in our robots.txt file.

Disallow: /*?s=

I also ask why "Disallow: /*?s=" would be used?  Why worry about parses that contain the letter "s"? If we remove it, what's the risk? Thanks so much in advance for any additional insight that can be shared - P

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing anything about your site. Presumably the application has, or at some point did have, a query string parameter of "s=" which indicated something that shouldn't be indexed. It could be short for "session", or "search", or maybe even "secret". Ideally, you'd look in version control and find who added the rule, and what their commit message was; but since you're asking strangers to help you guess, I presume that's not an option.

Comment: That's right...they original person who supported the site has left the building.   Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

This query is commonly used on WordPress-based sites.
There may be several types of content on your site and the site builder wanted to allow search only for certain types of content by another way of searching.
It makes sense for example on a store site that wants to restrict users from searching for the products using a customized search form so that they do not wander behind the scenes of the site.
Google's robot has a number of ways to identify if it's a WordPress based site, which is probably why it's looking for that end of the path.

Comment: Thank you!  It is indeed a WordPress based site.  We no longer do eCommerce on this site, so I'm going to assume the risk of removing "Disallow:/*?s=" from our robots.txt file is relatively low.  Thanks again for the contribution to our understanding - greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, for more information on WordPress security see the [official WordPress website](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/)